# Does small amount of Xmx cause java program to run inefficiently because of Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection

My point is, since there's limited amount of heapsize, does the JVM need to run garbage collection more frequently? and **practically**, is it a performance killer?

Comment: not as small as it cannot run, actually it can, I need to know about performance consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal amount of memory to use might be 2-5x the minimum heap to run the program.  How often the GC is run is inversely proportional to the amount of free memory after a GC.

> practically, is it a performance killer?

That depends on your application, but I would assume it is.

---

Given RAM is relative cheap compared to the cost of your time, I tend to make sure I have plenty of RAM. You can buy 16 GB for less than $80.

Comment: thank you @Peter, however that arises another question that how  the minimum required heap for a program can be measured, is there any specific tool or something?

Comment: You need to run the program long enough that it will load everything it might ever need to and look at the heap size after a full GC (which you can trigger with VisualVM) If its impossible to know what it might need to load, its impossible to say how much memory it might need.

Comment: Again, let me point you to visualVM (jvisualvm.exe under windows). Just run it (even without your app running) to get a visual impression of the VM running.

Comment: The jvisualvm.exe comes with the sdk. You should find it in the bin folder of your jdk installation.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of depends on the algorithm used for the gc and the jdk you are using. The normal gc is a killer as it stops execution of the other threads. If you are on jdk 1.6 or better you can make this visible using e.g. visualVM.
There are different gc algorithms to overcome this.  Here I would send you to the docs as they the differences best

Answer (score 0):

Finding the right balance between the memory requirements of your application and the memory allocation you give it (using Xmx) is a key performance tuning activity.

Yes, you want to make heap big enough so that the JVM does not end up thrashing on constant GC, which can absolutely be a performance killer.

What heap size you need is totally application dependent.

Comment: I also heard that too big heap size leads to GC pauses, however I don't know the technical causes of that, but actually I have two constraints: 1-RAM limitation 2-avoiding GC pauses, so I guess I should do some try and error, to find the optimum Xmx size for my case. thank you